# QtSpim Error "Attempt to execute non-instruction at 0x0040000c"

Tags: mips, qtspim

I just started learning MIPS 32 and try to run this code, it runs smoothly on MARS MIPS simulator but when I saved it into (.asm) file and tried to run on QtSpim, the console pops out with the message "Hello World" but an Error: "Attempt to execute non-instruction at 0x0040000c" also shows up, did I missed something or is any part incorrect?

[Error screnshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzlny.png)

I have also tried to uncheck the exception handler but to no avail.

- Here is the code:

  ```
  .data
      Message: .asciiz "Hello World"

  .text
      li $v0, 4
      la $a0, Message
      syscall
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to spim point of view, there are two problems with your program

1. spim expects a main and none is declared in your program.
2. spim continues executing the "program" after the last instruction. There should be a syscall 10 at the end to stop excution.

So, a working version of your program for spim is

```
.data
    Message: .asciiz "Hello World"

.text
main:                            # start of program
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, Message
    syscall
exit:
    li      $v0, 10              # syscall 10 terminates program 
    syscall                      # and exits
```

Indeed, spim is a bit touchy and I would advice you to use mars if it is possible. Besides that, it is a good practise to always add a main and an exit in your programs.